# Using SELECT-OPTIONS as an exporting parameters for class method?

Tags: parameters, abap

I'm currently having trouble with calling a method using a select option data type. It gives me the error: `S_NETWR` is not type-compatible with formal parameter `IN_NETWR`.

I'm not sure what I need to do to allow for me to export them as a parameter. Sorry, I'm new to ABAP. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Snippet of source code:

```
"set the audit at $50,000
lv_max = 50000.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK blk1 WITH FRAME TITLE text-001.
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_netwr FOR ekpo-netwr,
                s_datvr FOR nast-datvr NO INTERVALS.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK blk1.

*sets last run date from tvarvc
INITIALIZATION.
  PERFORM get_lastrun.

CALL METHOD lcl_audit->get_po
  EXPORTING
    in_netwr = s_netwr
    in_datvr = s_datvr
  IMPORTING
    out_po   = it_po
    .
```

`get_po` method from my class `zcl_audit_02`:

```
METHOD get_po.

  SELECT DISTINCT ekko~ebeln ekpo~netwr ekko~lifnr ekko~ekorg 
                  ekpo~werks ekko~ekgrp t024~eknam
  FROM ( ekpo
  INNER JOIN ekko
  ON ekko~ebeln = ekpo~ebeln

  INNER JOIN t024
  ON ekko~ekgrp = t024~ekgrp

  INNER JOIN nast
  ON nast~objky = ekko~ebeln )

  INTO TABLE out_po
  WHERE ekpo~netwr = in_netwr
  AND   nast~datvr = in_datvr.

  IF sy-subrc = 0.
    SORT out_po BY ebeln ASCENDING.
  ELSE.
    MESSAGE 'No Purchase Orders Found' TYPE 'I'.
  ENDIF.

ENDMETHOD.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please insert the code as part of your question instead of pasting it onto some external site that may or may not keep the code for an extended period of time.

Comment: ...and please include the method signatures as well as the method body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to define a type range in my class and exported s_netwr[] and s_datvr[]. This fixed the problem. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT-OPTIONS` creates an internal table with a header line. The problem is that header lines are no longer allowed when you're using ABAP OO. You'll have to get rid of the header line by passing `so_foo[]` to the method instead of `so_foo`. The brackets ensure that only the table component is addressed and the header line is ignored.

Comment: I passed the parameters as `s_netwr[]` and `s_datvr[]`, but I still get the same error. Am I missing something? Thanks again.

Comment: As I said, please provide the complete code including the method SIGNATURES.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what type your method parameter is. But you need it to be of the following.
Sign char 1
option char 2
low netwr
High netwr.
Create a structure in the data dictionary of this type and then a table type of that structure and use that table type as the data type for the parameter.